# Accessing zend view variables from breadcrumb partial

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I access a variable that is defined in the actual view from a breadcrumb partial?

I was trying with $this->myVar but I dont get anything.

I also try this and it works:

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
echo $view->myVar
```

Is this correct or there's a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Above answer by Davi Harkness is gr8 but if you still want to use it like $view->var then you don't even need to use partial view helper for that simply do

```
   $view = new Zend_View();
    $paths = $this->view->getScriptPaths();
    $view->addScriptPath($paths[0]);
    $view->name = "open source";
    $test = $view->render("test.phtml");
    echo $test;
```

Where test.phtml is inside /views/scripts dir of current module and contains

```
<?php echo $this->name?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Partial View Helper documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) specifically states that it "is used to render a specified template within its own variable scope." It does this by cloning the view and clearing out all existing variables in its `cloneView()` method:

```
public function cloneView()
{
    $view = clone $this->view;
    $view->clearVars();
    return $view;
}
```

Instead of coupling the partial to the views that call it you should have those views pass in the values the partial needs in an array.

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partial.phtml', array(
    'from' => 'Team Framework',
    'subject' => 'view partials',
)); ?>
```

Then the partial view script can access `$this->from` and `$this->subject`.

```
<?php // partial.phtml ?>
<ul>
    <li>From: <?php echo $this->escape($this->from) ?></li>
    <li>Subject: <?php echo $this->escape($this->subject) ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm talking about Rendering breadcrumbs using a partial view like in example #35 http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.breadcrumbs

Comment: Perhaps if you describe why you want to access view variables from the breadcrumbs someone will know a better method. For example, the view could add content to a placeholder which the breadcrumbs partial could render.